# How to scrape text between <br> tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract text string from a <p> tag, the text string I'm interested in is separated by a <br> tag.

```
<div id="foo">
 <p>
  " Data 1 : Lorem"
  <br>
  <br>
  " Data 2 : Ipsum"
  <br>
 </p>
<div>
```

Desired output :

```
Lorem
```

Using `bs4`, I'm stuck at :

```
collection1 = soup.select('div#foo > p:-soup-contains("Data 1 : ")').replace("Data 1 : ","").text.strip()
```

I don't know how to preceed to set a delimiter for the double quotes or the `<br>` tag? Any idea on how to proceed to get the desired output ?

I'm trying to scrap the details information of [this page](https://www.messika.com/fr/bracelet-pm-diamant-or-rose-d-vibes-12350-pg).
I've tried :

```
try:
   collection = soup.select('div#ui-accordion-1-panel-1 > div.tab-content-wrapper > p:-soup-contains("Collection")').text.strip()
except:
   collection = "" 
   print("No Collection")
```

Expecting to get the whole `<p>` tag but exception occured. I've been using this snippet on other scraps with Selenium and it did work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of getting that data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div id="foo">
 <p>
  " Data 1 : Lorem"
  <br>
  <br>
  " Data 2 : Ipsum"
  <br>
 </p>
<div>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
desired_data = soup.select_one('div[id="foo"] p').contents[0].split(':')[1].replace('"', '').strip()
print(desired_data)
```

Result:

```
Lorem
```

And here is one way (out of many others) to get the collection info from that page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.messika.com/fr/bracelet-pm-diamant-or-rose-d-vibes-12350-pg', headers=headers)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')
info = [x for x in soup.select_one('div[class="tab-content product-details"] p:-soup-contains("Univers")').contents if 'Collection :' in x][0].split(':')[-1].strip()
print('Collection:', info)
```

Result:

```
Collection: D-Vibes
```

Relevant documentation: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

There are not really `"` in the string and yes you could use `replace()`,`strip()`,... or use a `dict` that also provide all other features and let you pick from:

```
data = dict(f.split(' : ') for f in soup.select_one('.tab-content-wrapper > p').stripped_strings if ':' in f)
```

will lead to a `dict` like this:

```
{'Référence': 'Bracelet D-Vibes petit modèle 12350-PG', 'Univers': 'Joaillerie', 'Collection': 'D-Vibes', 'Type de bijou': 'Bracelet diamant', 'Métal': 'Or rose', 'Pierres': 'Diamant', 'Poids total diamants': '0,45 carat, qualité G/VS', 'Longueur chaîne': '18 cm (5 anneaux de fermeture)', 'Catégorie': 'Bracelet femme'}
```

so you could simply pick your `value` by `key`:

```
data.get('Collection') if data.get('Collection') else 'No Collection'
```

That will give you:

```
D-Vibes
```

or in case there is no  Collection

```
No Collection
```

---

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.messika.com/fr/bracelet-pm-diamant-or-rose-d-vibes-12350-pg').text)

data = dict(f.split(' : ') for f in soup.select_one('.tab-content-wrapper > p').stripped_strings if ':' in f)

data.get('Collection') if data.get('Collection') else 'No Collection'
```